# Does the order of addition expressions matter in Python?

Tags: python, methods

This sounds kind of stupid but I'm not talking about `1 + 2 = 2 + 1`. I am talking about where an object with an `__add__` method is added to a number. An example will be:

```
>>> class num:
...     def __add__(self,x):
...             return 1+x
... 
>>> n = num()
>>> 1+n
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'instance'
>>> n+1
2
>>>
```

I don't understand why the first one returns an error and the second one works like normal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Addition isn't assumed to be commutative - for example, `[1] + [2] != [2] + [1]` - so there's a separate method you need to implement when your object is on the right side of a `+` and the thing on the left doesn't know how to handle it.

```
def __radd__(self, other):
    # Called for other + self when other can't handle it or self's
    # type subclasses other's type.
```

Similar methods exist for all the other binary operations, all named by sticking an `r` in the same place.

Comment: And the `__radd__` is called only when the `__add__` of the left one fails?

Comment: @jakekimds: If the right operand's type is a subclass of the left operand's type, `__radd__` is tried first. Otherwise, `__radd__` is only tried if the left operand can't handle the operation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the order matters.

In the first case, the `__add__` method of `int` is called (which of course does not know how to add an instance of a non-number class to itself); in the second case, the `__add__` method of `num` is called.

If the `__add__` method fails, then Python can check for alternatives as user2357112 has pointed out.